# How to prevent the default redirect of a form submission on netlify?

Tags: reactjs, forms, netlify, onsubmit, submission

If i use `e.preventDefault()` , the form submssion aren't completed.

Using `action="/someurl"` looks like don't work too. However, it don't resolve my ask. I'd really like show a modal after the submission. Someone can help me?

Edit: It works now!

**The form:**

```
<form
        className="flex-column"
        name="form-contato"
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        ...
        <button type="submit" className="btn hover-border">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**How it works:**

```
  handleSubmit = e => {
fetch("/", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
  body: encode({ "form-name": "form-contato", ...this.state })
})
  .then(() => alert("Success!"))
  .catch(error => alert(error));
e.preventDefault(); };
```

Comment: could you post more code ?

Comment: thx for the support, i did it work. However i'll edit my post and show my code.